# How to get Hotspot login outside of Gnome

Tags: networking, gnome, hot-spot

Ubuntu 22.04, I sometimes use default Gnome, sometimes xmonad window manager.

When I connect to a hotspot that requires login, while using Gnome, a window for Hotspot login pops up.

When I do the same while using xmonad, nothing pops up.

- What is the name of the application that lets me enter hotspot login credentials?
- Can I start it manually?
- How can I automate its popping up when connecting to such a network, from xmonad?

Answer (score 2):

## What is the name of the application that lets me enter hotspot login credentials?

That application is just some embedded web browser pointed to an HTTP page (not HTTPS). We did this manually in the mid-2010s. I think it's called `/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-portal-helper` but its identity is not important because there is a simpler solution in the next section.

## Can I start it manually?

It would be simpler to open Firefox or another browser to any HTTP page. Just open a browser to `http://captive.apple.com` (not HTTPS) and you will be redirected to the hotspot login page. If there is no hotspot or if you're already logged in, you will see "Success". To make sure this works, either check that HTTPS-only mode is off, or just click past the warning.

## How can I automate its popping up when connecting to such a network, from xmonad?

GNOME is a desktop environment. xmonad seems to be just one component of a desktop environment, namely the window manager. You need some service daemon to do this. You would need to use whatever kind of strategy you are using for your power management, such as by installing separate software. This can be done by finding or writing some software that listens to NetworkManager over the system DBus for some signal, checks if that website returns "Success", and starts a web browser if not.

I currently don't have a public WiFi to test whether `/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-portal-helper` works outside of GNOME. Here is my attempt at an implementation that doesn't assume the user has GNOME installed:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Put this in `~/bin/captive.sh`
echo "[captive.sh] A script alternative to simulate GNOME's captive portal" >&2

# Ensure 1 instance of captive.sh, and prevent multiple orphaned nmcli processes
trap : SIGTERM
killall captive.sh nmcli 2> /dev/null
trap - SIGTERM
set -e

sleep 5 # Rate limit
while : ; do
  if ! pgrep -cu "$UID" xmonad > /dev/null; then
    echo '[captive.sh] Exiting for logout or other desktop environment'
    exit
  fi

  # Query any simple website that is HTTP not HTTPS.
  # The WiFi provider will intercept this and redirect it to
  # their website if they want you to log in.
  echo '[captive.sh] Checking connectivity' >&2
  if ! curl -s captive.apple.com | head -n1 | grep -q Success; then
    MSG='[captive.sh] Opening browser to log in. If there are any warnings, just click past them.'
    notify-send "$MSG"
    echo "$MSG" >&2
    xdg-open http://captive.apple.com
  else
    echo '[captive.sh] No login required' >&2
  fi

  sleep 5 # Rate limit

  # Listen for connected or connecting state, where
  # we need to check for a captive portal to log in to.
  # Ignore disconnect, where we have nothing to do.
  # Not taking advantage of NetworkManager's connectivity check
  # with the connecting state in case that isn't set up.
  echo '[captive.sh] Waiting for reconnect' >&2
  coproc nmcli monitor
  grep -q ': connect' <&"${COPROC[0]}"
  kill "$COPROC_PID"
done
```

Then `chmod +x ~/bin/captive.sh`, and either register it with xmonad's autostart if there is one, paste the following into `~/.config/autostart`

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Captive portal simulator
Description=Captive portal https://askubuntu.com/a/1501247/1004020
Exec=/bin/sh -c 'exec ~/bin/captive.sh'
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

A good looking alternative is https://github.com/elementary/capnet-assist . Another one is https://github.com/FiloSottile/captive-browser/ . The Arch Wiki script appears insecure and stuck on X11. I have not tested any except my own.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! There seems to be some caching going on as well, because entering the whole URL manually (see my own answer) let me use the network without entering credentials. I will try the http-no-S thing, however it will have to wait until next time the login times out, I don't know how to log out (disconnect is not enough). And for automating, do you know any example of application/package I could use for this? Can't I run the one from Gnome, since I already have it? What is it called?

Comment: @Gauthier It appears to be named `/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-portal-helper`. I don't have public WiFi to verify whether it works outside of GNOME, so I rolled my own before listing some alternatives. To log out of public WiFi, use both browser incognito mode or a new profile, and WiFi adapter MAC randomization before reconnecting.

Comment: What an awesome answer! I think the simplest is to have a bookmark to http://captive.apple.com, and click that. I wonder if the NetworkManager could be hooked up to `/usr/libexec/gnome-shell-portal-helper` to execute. I'm not even sure what it actually does, more than what your fine script does. Running it from a terminal, it dies upon network loss. Neither `--help` nor `man` were helpful.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Gnome is just opening an URL to the hotspot login page. I was able to copy this URL and open it in a browser in xmonad to get to the login page.

But I suspect that this URL might change with time, and that it actually comes from the Wifi itself. So I suppose I might instead need to extract that URL from the Wifi, somehow.

Comment: As I explained earlier, this URL comes from a redirect. Just open any HTTP (no HTTPS) page such as `http://captive.apple.com`. The WiFi will intercept this and redirect you to the page you need